# Proving vectors are linealy independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $v_1,...,v_n$ be linealy independent vectors in $R^m$ and let $w = a_1v_1 + ...+a_nv_n$ with real numbers $a_1, ... a_n$, be linear combination of these vectors.

Prove if $a_1 \not=0$, then the vector $w, v_2, ..., v_n$ are linearly independent

So far, what I have thought is forming a formula like this: $x_1w + x_2v_2 + ... + x_nv_n = 0$, because $v_1, ..., v_n$ is linearly independent vectors, so $x_2 = ... = x_n = 0$, then now we need to prove $x_1 = 0$ so these vector will be linearly independent. But from here, I don't know how to process further more in this problem, can anyone help me out with a way to solve this or a better alternative solution is appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $w $ has a contribution from $v_1$, then any linear combination of $w,v_2,\dots,v_n $ can be written as a linear combination of  $v_1,\dots,v_n $.  That's suppose $x_1w+x_2v_2+\dots+x_nv_n=0$.  Then  $x_1a_1v_1+(x_1a_2+x_2)v_2+\dots+(x_1a_n+x_n)v_n=0\implies x_1=(x_1a_2+x_2)=\dots=(x_1a_n+x_n)=0\implies x_1=x_2=\dots=x_n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with $x_1 w + x_2 v_2 + \cdots + x_n v_n = 0$ is a good start.

You cannot conclude $x_2 = \cdots = x_n = 0$, since linear independence of $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ doesn't directly imply anything about $x_1 w + x_2 v_2 + \cdots + x_n v_n$.

However, you do know $w = a_1 v_1 + \cdots + a_n v_n$, so you can write your original equation as
$$x_1 (a_1 v_1 + \cdots + a_n v_n) + x_2 v_2 + \cdots + x_n v_n = 0$$

You can rearrange the left-hand side into the form
$$c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + \cdots + c_n v_n = 0$$
where $c_i$ can be written in terms of $x$s and $a$s. Now you can use linear independence of $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ to deduce that $c_1 = \cdots = c_n = 0$, and write down what this means for $x_1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't really understand the part that you said rearrange the left-hand side into another form, can you explain it to me

Comment: @Peter Chris Custer's answer spells this out.